# É possível fazer uma quebra de linha dentro de um placeholder?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Gostaria de realizar uma quebra de linha dentro do *placeholder* de uma textarea, para que fique de exemplo como os usuários podem preenchê-la.

Há alguma forma de fazer isso?

```
<textarea placeholder="Excelentíssimo Senhor
                       Professor Doutor"
          class="form-control" id="interessado">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É possível usando o HTML *entity* de quebra de linha **`&#10;`**.

```html
<textarea placeholder="Excelentíssimo Senhor&#10;Professor Doutor"
          class="form-control" id="interessado" style="width: 500px; height: 150px;">
</textarea>
```